# ¿Cómo resolver el error Function name must be a string?

Tags: php, sql

El error dice:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_query in
> /storage/ssd3/740/17554740/public_html/proyecto final/registrarse.php
> on line 12
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
> /storage/ssd3/740/17554740/public_html/proyecto
> final/registrarse.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /storage/ssd3/740/17554740/public_html/proyecto final/registrarse.php
> on line 12"

```
$resultado = $mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'conexionBD.php';


if (!empty($_POST['nombre'])) {
  
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO INGRESANTE(nombre) VALUES ('$nombre')";
  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
 if ($result) {
   ?>
   <h3> te registraste correctamente</h3>
   <?php
  } else {
    ?>
   <h3> ups, ha ocurrido un error</h3>
   <?php
  }
 
  var_dump($result);

  if ($result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
  }
 
} else{
        ?>
   <h3> por favor complete el campo</h3>
   <?php
}
?>
```

No se porque me da error, encima me estoy basando en un video de youtube que lo hace tal cual. La única diferencia con el video es que él sube los datos en un server localhost. Yo lo subo a un server mediante heidisql. Capaz debe haber alguna diferencia ahí, igualmente la conexión a la bd es exitosa.

Comment: Falta información, con el código que publicas solo podemos saber que el string de tu conexion es **$conn** , pero no sabemos que lleva la variable $sql , te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y pongas mas código, saludos.

Comment: Debes agregar todo el codigo necesario para hacer un [mre]

Answer (score 4):

Has sido tan, vamos a decir, descuidado, que has antepuesto $ a la función mysqli_query. De esta forma, el intérprete de PHP entiende que estás usando una función, que será el valor de la cadena $mysqli_query. Pero claro, la cadena $mysqli_query no la has definido y por tanto no contiene nada, así que no es un string. Y de ahí el correctísimo mensaje de error.

Es así:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Por otro lado, no entiendo la gente que ha comentado que hace falta información, ¿no tenéis ojos? Desde el cariño ;)

Comment: Gracias jose. Pero al corregir eso me aparece este error: "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /storage/ssd3/740/17554740/public_html/proyecto final/registrarse.php on line 18"

Comment: Se supone que $conn la has definido dentro del archivo conexionBD.php, compruébalo.

Comment: Sisi $conn la definí en el archivo de la conexión.

Comment: El error dice que le has pasado un objeto. ¿Usaste mysqli_connect()? Quizá usaste new mysqli(). Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo usar estilo orientado a objetos, que por procedimientos.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Gracias!! era eso.

Comment: mejor usa: `$conn->query($sql);` orientado a objeto es mas efectivo y no tienes que escribir tnto código.

Comment: @LucasBrumatti Acepta la respuesta si era eso ;)